# Remove emails from server - Zimbra

Tags: email-server, zimbra

I have a Zimbra 6 emailing server. The space on the server is almost full. I deleted all the emails from my account, but unfortunately, the mailing server didn't release any bit. From what I understand, the emails from my account haven't been removed from the server. How can I set up the server to delete the emails from the server when I delete the email from my Imbox?

Thanks in advance,
Romulus

Comment: Let's start with the obvious: have you emptied the Trash folder on your account?

Comment: Yes. I emptied the Trash.

Comment: I was thinking that should be a variable to enable/disable deleting emails from the server. But I didn't find it. I find it for others email-servers during the research.

Comment: Are you sure it's your mailbox that's taking up disk space? Maybe you have some runaway log file? Try logging into the machine and finding out exactly which directories/files are taking up the space.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the mailing box take this space. I check on the server and all the disk space is taken by the "/data" folder where are stored all the emails.

Comment: In Zimbra, an email is stored only once. So if you have an email in your mailbox and another person has a CC of that email, Zimbra stores it once. So if you delete it, it is still in the other person's mailbox and it remains there. Both would have to delete it to get rid of it on disk. You may have some mailbox with copies of all emails? A Spam learning box with copies of the spam messages? etc.

Comment: Hi ETL. This make sense. Someboday else have the same email in his emailbox. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi, did you resolved this *mysterious* issue? Can you share the solution in answer box below?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately i don't have a test environment. I tried on the production environment, but all the sent and received emails are also backed up. If the email is saved only one time, even if it's send to multiple users, this means the space on the server is well structured.

Comment: answer from zimbra wiki. here: https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/DB_not_releasing_disk_space_after_deleting_data

Comment: The mails are not stored in /data, they are stored in /store. In /data/db you have the mysql database, in /data/tmp you have temporary files that can fill up under certain conditions.